# Cannot invoke method buildscript on null project

Tags: android, gradle

I am new to Gradle, I'm trying to build a plugin to do some aop using ASM, I succeeded created my plugin once.

However when I'm trying to create a new one in a new project, I met this problem: "cannot invoke method build script on null project", I did some searching but couldn't find solution that solves my problem.

[image]

Comment: Post here, code of project level build.gradle file

Comment: I somehow fixed it by cleaning and rebuilding project, i dont know why though. If you re worrying my gradle and plugin version, they are compatible, but thanks anyway